# When I save data in a text file there is a redundant line at the end, what is it(C#)?

Tags: c#, text, save

I faced an interesting point. I have a foreach loop for writing data in a List array. Interestingly, there is this message at the end of the text file :

**System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double]**

What is it? 
Is it because of this line (writer.WriteLine(BoundaryLayerCheck0.ToString());)  ?

```
string path = string.Concat(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"\Output\+1+".txt");

        using (FileStream fs0 = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs0))
        {
            foreach (double x in BoundaryLayerCheck0)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(x);
            }
            writer.WriteLine(BoundaryLayerCheck0.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: "Is it because of this line...?" Yes. It would be very simple to comment out that line of code and test your theory.

Comment: -1 No effort put in to find out the issue. As itsme86 said, you could have very simply tested your theory.

Comment: -1 The question is misleading, when I read the title, I thought maybe the OP had count some intersting issue in `WriteLine` or `StringBuilder`.. then I found this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your own question.

`BoundaryLayerCheck0.ToString()` will return the fully qualified type of the object (unless you have overridden the `ToString()` method.

More info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx